# How to retry the particular statement where errors occurs in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am asking user inputs and validating that inputs if validation fails i am asking user to enter 
valid input ...

This is how I am doing this

```
     begin 

          enter_user_first_name
          is_first_name_valid?

          enter_user_last_name
          is_last_name_valid?.

          enter_user_age
          greater_than_eq_18?

          enter_user_gender
          gender_valid?

     rescue => error
        p error
        retry
     else

     end
```

Here first I am entering input and then validating , 
But the problem I am facing that when one statement in between fails it start executing all statement of begin block again ,  for example , if user enters last name incorrectly it start asking first name again , instead of asking just last name  .

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a helper method and then call it for each of the blocks that can be retried:

```
def with_retry
  begin
    yield
  rescue => error
    puts error
    retry
  end
end

with_retry do
  enter_user_first_name
  is_first_name_valid?
end

with_retry do
  enter_user_last_name
  is_last_name_valid?
end

with_retry do
  enter_user_age
  greater_than_eq_18?
end

with_retry do
  enter_user_gender
  gender_valid?
end
```

---

*with `send`* (however I would advise against using `send` too much in your program, it can make it more difficult to know what's happening)

```
operations = {
  enter_user_first_name: :is_first_name_valid?,
  enter_user_last_name:  :is_last_name_valid?,
  enter_user_age:        :greater_than_eq_18?,
  enter_user_gender:     :gender_valid?
}

operations_each do |input_fn, validation_fn|
  begin
    send(input_fn)
    send(validation_fn)
  rescue => e
    puts e
    retry
  end
end
```

end

Comment: What if , I have many data inputs like a typical form page can have , then this code will look like very clumpsy i.e i need with try for each user input . Is there any other method to do that ?

Comment: Hi Yashvi, yes there are other ways to do it, but with the limited information you've shown (what's actually in the methods?) it's hard to say a better way. See my edit to the answer, I will show you a way to do it with `send`. Although I generally avoid using `send` in my code unless it's really necessary.